# Grails: How do a validate POST body consisting of a list of items using a command object?

Tags: grails, grails3, grails-validation

I am facing some issues with writing custom validators (Commands) in grails 3.3.3. Specifically, I am trying to validate POST request whose body is composed of a list of items. This is what I have...

The Command:

```
class VoteCommand implements Validateable {


    List<VoteItem> postList = [].withLazyDefault { new ListItem() }

    static constraints = {
        postList nullable: false
    }

    class ListItem implements Validateable {
        String tag
        String some_id

        static constraints = {
            some_id nullable: false, blank: false
            tag nullable: false, blank: false
            tag inList: Tag.values() as List
        }
    }
}
```

AND the Payload:

```
{
    "noteVotesButWorks": [

                {
                    "tag": "good"
                },
                {
                    "tag": "bad"
                }
        ]
}
```

This payload passes the validation check in my controller action.

```
 def save(VoteCommand command) {


            println(command.errors) //grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors



            if (command.hasErrors()) {
                respond params.errors, view: 'create'
            } else {
                withFormat {
                    '*' { render status: CREATED }
                }
            }

}
```

After making the POST request to this action, I get a `201` and `grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors` printed to stdout.

Please, can someone here give me some pointers?

Comment: This is not really related to your question but you have `respond params.errors`.  Did you intend `respond command.errors`?

Comment: Also you have a `withFormat` block with only 1 case in it which is the `'*'` wildcard so `withFormat` isn't buying you anything.  You could simply make the body of your `else` block to be `render status: CREATED` without the `withFormat` contraption and still have the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Please, can someone here give me some pointers?

Your payload includes the key `noteVotesButWorks`.  The data binder is going to create an instance of `VoteCommand` and then look to see if there is a `noteVotesButWorks` property on that instance, and there isn't, so the data binder doesn't really have anything to do.  Your `VoteCommand` instance is then validated, which passes because your only constraint is `postList nullable: false`, which passes because `postList` is not null.

That all is working as designed.  You probably want the key in your payload map to match the name of the `List` property in `VoteCommand`.

Separate from all of that, there is no good reason to include `.withLazyDefault { new ListItem() }` in your property initialization.  You don't really have to initialize the property at all.  The data binder will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want `nullable: false` for postList.  An empty list is not null.  I think you want `minSize: 1`.

Comment: That kinda worked but doesn't validate the individual `ListItems` just validates the `votes` list's size

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize those were failing too.  Looking at this again.  When you save, what do you get if you print command*.postList?  I'm curious if your payload is even being converted to ListItems.